# Windows XP, Vista, 7 ... estimated percentages of users?

Tags: windows

This is a little unusual question, but I need it for a report I'm making. Is there someplace, or do you know perchance, what is the current estimate of the percentage of users with Microsoft's OS's, by OS?

Uhmm, I don't know how to phrase this better, I'm not a native english speaker, but I think you'll understand what I mean. What I'm looking for is this (without the made up data):

XP 67%
  Vista 69%
  7 12%

Where could one find some sort of statistical data like that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems).

It at least gives you a starting point.

Anapologetos

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. "Usage share" - couldn't remember the phrase for to search. Thank you !